# What are the labels for this aircraft's JSON?

Tags: online-tracking, flight-data-monitoring

Can someone please help me identify the labels associated with the below JSON?

The data comes from [FlightRadar24](https://data-live.flightradar24.com/zones/fcgi/feed.js?bounds=56.85,47.15,-28.97,28.13&faa=1&mlat=1&flarm=1&adsb=1&gnd=0&air=1&vehicles=0&estimated=1&maxage=7200&gliders=0&stats=1)

```
c5cded9":[
          "06A0F8",
          51.3056,
          6.4601,
          283,
          43000,
          459,
          "3245",
          "F-EDDK1",
          "A359",
          "A7-ALD",
          1486231556,
          "DOH",
          "LHR",
          "QR1",
          0,
          64,
          "QTR1",
          0
]
```

I get that `51.3056` & `6.4601` are the latitude and longitude. I also get that `43000` is the altitude and `1486231556` is a timestamp, but I do not know what the others should be...

For example, `LHR` I guess is London Heathrow, but is what is the official term?

I'd like official terms to match the JSON.

I want to do some data visualizations with the aircraft data.

Comment: It might help if you edit your question to indicate where the JSON comes from an it's purpose.

Comment: FR24 explicitly does not have a published API, and they probably won't take too kindly to someone using their internal API (which they should secure.... ).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Community wiki answer:

```
06A0F8,         Mode S ICAO 24-bit address
51.3056,        lat
6.4601,         long
283,            heading
43000,          altitude in feet
459,            ground speed in knots
3245,           squawk (transponder code)
F-EDDK1,        radar receiver identifier
A359,           ICAO aircraft type Airbus A350-900
A7-ALD,         aircraft tail number / registration
1486231556,     time-stamp
DOH,            departure airport Doha (IATA code)
LHR,            arrival airport Heathrow (IATA code)
QR1,            flight number (IATA)
0,              ground flag (1=on ground, 0=airborne)
64,             vertical speed (feet/min)
QTR1,           ATC call-sign
0
```

Comment: I don't know enough about aviation to edit but I googled the first string and found this page: https://www.avdelphi.com/flight.html?callsign=QTR015. So it looks like Airframe? The data on that page lines up with the data here.